# Scroll control in jVectorMap

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, jvectormap

I am using `jVectorMap`, everything works fine without zooming.

But when a user zoomed in the page I need to allow the user to scroll the the map using a vertical and horizontal scroll bar.

I have tried to add `overflow-y: scroll;` And other many options to do the scrolling but nothing works perfectly.

I can set the width and height of div to get the scroll bar but it is not related with map zoom in and zoom out.

So I am expecting a scroll bar horizontally and vertically which using that user can see the full map if even it is zoomed.

I have seen a map with below image in the internet 
[image]

But No idea how can I add a scroll button control like this in `jVector map`. 
Can someone help me to resolve this issue.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need two steps:

1. To understand how the map is translated inside the container, initialize the Map with the `onViewportChange` event:

   ```
   $("#map").vectorMap({
     map: "world_mill",
     // set map properties, series, and so on
     //...
     onViewportChange: function(event, scaleFactor,transX,transY){
       // look at the values here:
       console.log("Viewport changed",scaleFactor,transX,transY);
     }
   });
   ```
2. To the point: 
   to apply a map translation, set your desired X and Y panning, at the end invoke the `applyTransform` function:

   Example:

   ```
   var worldMap = $("#map").vectorMap("get", "mapObject");
   worldMap.transX = -100;
   worldMap.applyTransform();
   ```

---

Additional information:

Luckily, jVectorMap will do the range checking for you, so for your pan buttons you can also simply use somethng like:

```
worldMap.transX -= (10 * worldMap.scale); // move left
worldMap.transX += (10 * worldMap.scale); // move right
worldMap.transY -= (10 * worldMap.scale); // move up
worldMap.transY += (10 * worldMap.scale); // move down
```

You will find the range check in the `applyTransform` function in [jVectorMap source code](https://github.com/bjornd/jvectormap).

Credits: [Kirill Lebedev](https://stackoverflow.com/cv/kirilllebedev), the great author of jVectorMap.

---

Lastly, the re-center button:
You can get the center of the map as follows:

```
var mapCX = (worldMap.width / 2) * worldMap.scale + worldMap.transX * worldMap.scale;
var mapCY = (worldMap.height / 2) * worldMap.scale + worldMap.transY * worldMap.scale;
```

---

As you haven't provide any source code, I can't help further, but if you have understand the concept, the transformation between your scrollbar range and the map translation is trivial easy.

Comment: applyTransform is not defined error is coming , I have a custom button append to the map and I have tried to call the applyTranform from that button click

Comment: working when i call it like worldMap.applyTransform()

Comment: But the issue is when we cannot go for a long click event here , for transformation user needs to click again and again , is there any way to do the same with a scroll bar ??

Comment: In your picture, the scrollbar is for zooming, whereas the knob has buttons for panning and centering. Anyway, if you need a scrollbar, here is one: http://baijs.com/tinyscrollbar/

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV: THX for your appreciation, feel free to ask again, I am glad to help You!

Comment: I have tried to use tiny scroll bar here , but unfortunately it is not working I have tried the same tiny scroll bar for google map still that is also not working , map itself is not visible , can you please provide a fiddle or codepen link with maps with tiny scroll bar ?

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV: IMHO, I believe another answer won't fit here. please post another question with your code and i will try to adjust it. Without code it is too hard to guess what is not working.